# Photoshop looks terrible in 13.10

Tags: wine, fonts, playonlinux

I have been using Photoshop CS2 for years on various versions of Linux and Ubuntu. In recent years, I've found that installing it with PlayOnLinux has had the most consistently reliable results.

However, on a fresh install of 13.10, the Photoshop interface looks terrible. The fonts are clunky, and in the image below, it's not an image of a white box on a black backround with a square drawn in a black line. It's actually just a plain white image. The surrounding black area is where ordinarily Photoshop is supposed to be a neutral gray canvas, and the black square is a selection area, which is supposed to be a dotted line.

How do I get Photoshop's proper interface, as I've had with every version of Linux and Ubuntu previous to this?

Here is a screen grab:

[image: Photoshop looks terrible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out not to be the latest version of Ubuntu, but the latest version of Wine.

I reinsalled Photoshop following [the instructions on this web page](http://setuix.com/install-photoshop-linux/), with the additional step of selecting an earlier version of Wine. Current version of Wine is 1.7.x, but I used 1.6.2, and now Photoshop looks right.

Here's how Photoshop looks when it's displaying correctly:

[image: correct Photoshop GUI]

Answer (score 0):

You can fix fonts by installing ms fonts. Open your software center and search for them.

By the way looking for review of application in winehq is also good idea.so that you can know what's the problem is & if somebody did provideed any solution you can use that.

Bottom line is look at winehq also.